# MongoDB Query Returns Empty Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Have a basic express app going that is connected to an almost .5 GB MongoDB Database...When I run:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    medical_data.find({'State':'CT'}, function(err, data) {
    console.log(data)
    res.render('index');
    });
});
```

I get a blank array returned:

```
[]
GET / 304 87.233 ms - -
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 4.842 ms - -
```

Here is the entry from MongoLab that I'm trying to query for:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5671dfafd7f6fdd02436682e"
    },
    "Street": "65 KANE ST",
    "City": "WEST HARTFORD",
    "State": "CT"
}
```

And here is my medical_data model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var medical_data_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Street: String,
  City: String,
  State: String
});

var medical_data = mongoose.model('medical_data', medical_data_schema);
// Make this available to our other files
module.exports = medical_data;
```

Why am I getting a blank array back? If I run `findOne` instead of `find` I get `null` in the console

I've run other succesfull node apps before but none with a database as big as this, so I think it might be a timeout issue? I'm not sure, any help would be amazing.

Comment: Hmm, if you're getting a response back it's not likely to be a timeout I don't think (but it still could be, of course). Have you tried running a 'raw' mongo query on the command line? If you can try that and get the record back you want, then we can partition the problem and look more @ mongoose :)

Comment: and at the same time (but in a separate step) I would suggest running some sort of $has or $exists w/ mongoose to be sure you're getting results back at all :)

Comment: Was the database created with Mongoose as well (using the schema you post), or are you trying to retrofit a Mongoose schema on top of an existing database?

Comment: fitting a mongoose schema ontop of an existing database

Comment: thanks for reaching out mark, i haven't installed the shell yet....unless it came with the original mongodb package, i'll look into it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Fitting a Mongoose schema on top of an existing database can be tricky. For one, Mongoose will determine the collection name by pluralizing the model name; so in your case, Mongoose will use the collection `medical_datas`, and my guess is that it's actually called `medical_data`.

You can specify the collection name to use for a schema by using the [`collection`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection) option:

```
var medical_data_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Street : String,
  City   : String,
  State  : String
}, { collection : 'medical_data' });
```

Comment: Thanks a million robert, that worked. So do i have this right...by default mongoose pluralizes what you name your model?

Comment: @AdamWeitzman the MongoDB collection name that Mongoose will use is the pluralized (and lowercased, I think) version of the model name (so if your model is called `User`, it will use the `users` collection).

Comment: You saved my day. I was thinking of some mistake in my code. It works fine now. I have updated your answer which works for me. Thank you man!!!!!

Comment: Wow. This gave me nightmares last night... 7:25am, and we're GTG - THX!

Comment: @robertklep Thanks mate! I really wonder why mongoose hasn't resolved this issue. Do we have any open ticket for this problem?

Comment: @Ashfedy it's by design.

Comment: I could almost say that I'm forever greatful. Thanks Robert, this saved me.

Comment: Who comes up with the idea to auto pluralize names...this took me so long to figure out. Thnx a lot!