# Can't fetch data from second collection in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

Able to fetch data from a collection in MongoDB but unable to fetch the second collection in my database. Able to connect to the database since get '/rooms' works but not '/names'.

**This Works:**

Models Folder:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let roomsList = Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    img: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: '1'
    }
})


let Roomers = module.exports = mongoose.model('therooms', roomsList);
```

App.js :

```
let Roomers = require('./models/roomListing')

app.get("/rooms", function (req, res) {
    Roomers.find({}, function(err, rooms){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(rooms)
             //shows all data
        }

    });
});
```

**Does Not Work:**

Models folder:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let nameList = Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: 'nothing'
    }
})

let Namers = module.exports = mongoose.model('otherstuff', nameList);
```

App.js :

```
let Namers = require('./models/nameList')


app.get("/names", function (req, res) {

    Namers.find({}, function(err, ert){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(ert);
        }
    });
});
```

Rooms Collection ( therooms ):

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5fb88eb9e3499c4a7c5d5163"
    },
    "title": "Small Loft",
    "price": {
        "$numberDouble": "100.0"
    },
    "img": "1"
}
```

Names Collection ( otherstuff ):

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5fb88ee4e3499c4a7c5d5164"
},
"name": "yung impulse"
}
```

Comment: Is it giving any error ? What does the console.log statement in the second example print ?

Comment: @NaveenChahar Names collection (other stuff) prints out an empty array when get is called

Comment: are you certain that your otherstuff collection contains some data ? If yes how did you verify it.

Comment: @NaveenChahar The data is there in the collection because I can look it up in Atlas but don't know why a find query returns empty

Comment: check out this question and see if it solves your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344492/mongodb-query-returns-empty-array